# Transform PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that I'm trying to transform into a different format, the only way I can think to do it would be a lot longer than it seems like it should need.

Example data:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [type] => a
    [value] => 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [type] => a
    [value] => 2
    )
[2] => Array (
    [type] => a
    [value] => 3
    )
[3] => Array (
    [type] => b
    [value] => 1
    )
[4] => Array (
    [type] => b
    [value] => 4
    )
[5] => Array (
    [type] => f
    [value] => 2
    )
)
```

Into:

```
Array (
'a' => Array(1,2,3),
'b' => Array(1,4),
'f' => Array(2)
)
```

Comment: "would be a lot longer than it seems like it should need", mind post your attempt? It could be already the fastest you could do, hm..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Sorry for not showing my attempt - to be honest I was too embarrassed by how convoluted (read: bad) it was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $element) 
    $newArray[$element["type"]][] = $element["value"];
```

[Seems to do the trick rather nicely.](http://3v4l.org/4uCjg)

Comment: Thanks! Clean and simple. I'd missed using $array[] = $var to push a single element, this is much better than keeping track of the indexes.

Comment: @JSP64: You can also use array_push().